# "Connection Reset" occurs in Solr client side

Tags: java, performance, tomcat, solr, config

We are encountering a "connection reset" error when we call the SOLR server. And our concurrent load is rather small.

Here is the Tomcat connector config for SOLR:

```
<Connector port="8983" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
           connectionTimeout="20000" maxThreads="40000" minSpareThreads="400" maxSpareThreads="5000" maxKeepAliveRequests="100" URIEncoding="UTF-8"
           redirectPort="8943" />
```

And  here is we got from our SOLR client:

```
Caused by: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CommonsHttpSolrServer.request(CommonsHttpSolrServer.java:472)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CommonsHttpSolrServer.request(CommonsHttpSolrServer.java:243)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.QueryRequest.process(QueryRequest.java:89)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServer.query(SolrServer.java:122)

... 36 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:168)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:218)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:237)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser.readRawLine(HttpParser.java:78)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser.readLine(HttpParser.java:106)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.readLine(HttpConnection.java:1116)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$HttpConnectionAdapter.readLine(MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:1413)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.readStatusLine(HttpMethodBase.java:1973)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.readResponse(HttpMethodBase.java:1735)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:1098)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:398)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323)
```

After trouble shooting by reading through the SOLR client code, we found this may be due to an improper connection timeout setting in SOLR's Tomcat config. We decide to change it to default (infinite timeout). So, my question is, will it bring　out other performance issues when setting this value to infinite?

Comment: Is solr server fronted by some web server (eg. apache)?  The worst that can happen, IMO, is some client making a connection and not sending anything on the wire after that, and subsequently disconnecting, causing file descriptor leaks.  A web server in front of that could mitigate this problem.

Answer (score 0):

What is the client that is calling Solr?  and the query made?  Is the query for whatever reason a very long running one that does not return?